# Is it possible to explain why the Lucas-Lehmer primality test works to someone who is not a math professional?

Tags: prime-numbers, proof-explanation, lucas-lehmer-test

I know the [proof of the Lucas-Lehmer test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test#Proof_of_correctness) is based on group theory.

My math knowledge is not deep and that is why I don't understand why the test is working.

Is it possible to explain to someone who is not familiar with group theory why the test works?

(I know how to perform the test but I want to understand the logic behind it.)

Comment: Have you tried reading the proof in that link? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I doubt that there is an easier proof. This result is not trivial.